# HTTP Status 404 in Struts2 web application

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, struts2

Here is my set up:

Specs:

- Tomcat 7.0.55
- jdk1.8.0_11
- Eclipse Luna
- Win 8.1

I have a Dynamic Web Project set up in Eclipse titled "Struts2Test" with following structure. Note: I am highlighting only the folders and files relevant to this question.

```
Struts2Test (project name)
 - [Java Resources]
   - [src]
     - [com.struts2action] (package)
         - HelloWorldAction.java
   - [Libraries]
     - [Struts2] (user defined library)
         - antlr-2.7.2.jar
         - bsf-2.3.0.jar
         - commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
         - commons-chain-1.2.jar
         - commons-digester-1.8.jar
         - commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
         - commons-io-1.1.jar
         - commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
         - commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
         - jstl-1.0.2.jar
         - oro-2.0.8.jar
         - standard-1.0.6.jar
         - struts-core-1.3.10.jar
         - struts-el-1.3.10.jar
         - struts-extras-1.3.10.jar
         - struts-faces-1.3.10.jar
         - struts-mailreader-dao-1.3.10.jar
         - struts-scripting-1.3.10.jar
         - struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar
         - struts-tiles-1.3.10.jar
 - [Web Content]
   - [WEB-INF]
     - [classes]
         - struts.xml
     - web.xml
   - error.jsp
   - index.jsp
   - success.jsp
```

**web.xml**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
               xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
               id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

              <display-name>Struts2Test</display-name>

              <welcome-file-list>
                  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
               </welcome-file-list>

               <filter>
                  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
                  <filter-class>
                     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
                  </filter-class>
               </filter>

               <filter-mapping>
                  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
                  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
               </filter-mapping>

            </web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
               "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
               "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
            <struts>


               <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

                    <!--  URL: hello  -->  
                  <action name="hello" 
                        class="com.struts2action.HelloWorldAction" 
                        method="execute">
                        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
                        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
                  </action>
                  <!-- more actions can be listed here -->

               </package>
               <!-- more packages can be listed here -->

            </struts>
```

**HelloWorldAction.java**

```
    package com.struts2action;

    public class HelloWorldAction {

        public String execute() {
            System.out.println("HelloWorldAction - called");
            return "success";
        }
    }
```

I run and compile the program. I call the following:

```
http://localhost:8085/Struts2Test/hello.action
```

I keep getting the following error:

HTTP Status 404 - /Struts2Test/hello.action

type Status report
message /Struts2Test/hello.action
description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.55

Could anyone please advise what the issue with my configuration is?

Comment: I am baffled; you say Struts 2 but all the libraries you show are for Struts 1. The GXP issue is because you have the GXP plugin jar deployed but not its dependencies; you should only be deploying the plugins you're actually using.

Comment: @Dave Newton - good point. And you're absolutely right, Dave. I wrote down an incorrect version of the jars. However, I was using the Struts2 jars in the user-defined library. The GXP was definitely a part of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved my issue by removing the user-defined library and I added the jars directly to WEB-INF/classes folder. Please, note that the jars on the picture are different from the jars listed in my question. I am only starting to learn about Struts2 so I am not even sure whether I need all those jars in there. Either way, thanks you all for your help and feedback.

[image]

Comment: I encountered the same issue, changed the folders and files structure same as you illustrated above, but it is not helping me. My Struts2 version is `struts-2.5.10.1`, `xwork-core-x.y.jar` and `common-logging-api.x.y.jar`are disappeared from this version. Do you think its because of that?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same code on Apache Tomcat 6.0 and It is working fine there.

On Tomcat7 you may need to use Struts2 Prepare and Execute Filter.

Try with replacing your filter code with following as Filter Dispatcher is97 deprecated now.

```
<filter-class>
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
</filter-class>
```

Just one more question, are you able to see your System out statement on console?

Comment: I found my issue. A library dependency issue. "Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer"
I left only the these jar's in my library and code started working...
commons-fileupload-x.y.z.jar
commons-io-x.y.z.jar
commons-lang-x.y.jar
commons-logging-x.y.z.jar
commons-logging-api-x.y.jar
freemarker-x.y.z.jar
javassist-.xy.z.GA
ognl-x.y.z.jar
struts2-core-x.y.z.jar
xwork-core.x.y.z.jar

Changing the filter class to org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter gives me 404 with no 404 and I don't see my systout.

Comment: *edit: Changing the filter class to the suggested value gives me 404 when loading index.jsp with no errors in the console. And I don't see my systout in the console either.

Comment: normally 404 not found is because of 1) the file you redirect is not there. 2) your project was has errors in codes 3) Dependency are not fulfilled.

Comment: Are you calling your hello.action from index.jsp?
Just try to put the url http://localhost:8085/Struts2Test/hello.action in browser after start the server and then in your console whether your execute method print sysout statement.
if you are calling your action from index.jsp please share your action calling code from index.jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping the jar files inside /WEB-INF/lib